# How do spray's directives correspond to continuations?

Tags: scala, spray, continuations, continuation-passing

I fail to see how spray's directives correspond to [continuation passing style (CPS)](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Continuation_passing_style).

More specifically, a continuation is `(a -> r) -> r` (in Haskell), but I cannot find where is this type (`(a -> r) -> r`) when using spray [directives](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.4/spray-routing/key-concepts/directives/) (which have the type of `Route->Route` where `type Route = RequestContext => Unit`).

Nor `Route->Route` neither  `type Route = RequestContext => Unit` do resemble `(a -> r) -> r`, so how do directives relate to [CPS](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Continuation_passing_style) ?

Could someone show how spray's directive [correspond](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.4/spray-routing/key-concepts/routes/) to continuation passing style ?

Answer (score 0):

A directive, in its simplest form, is defined as

```
abstract class Directive[L <: HList] {
  def happly(f: L => Route): Route
}
```

which is exactly a `(a -> r) -> r`. What you see in spray [directives](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.4/spray-routing/key-concepts/directives/) documentation is a high-level DSL which builds `Directive` instances under the hood. You can see the full definition in [Directive.scala](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-routing/src/main/scala/spray/routing/Directive.scala#L58)